# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am pretty much new to node / express and following a youtube tutorial to build a MERN Stack app. But my node server is giving this error

[image: error]

I tried restarting server many times it happening again and again. **I got the idea it happens when we send two responses for one request** but I don't think its the case here.

Btw here is the route it is pointing to in the error (in the try catch error response line)

```js
// GET RANDOM
router.get("/random", verify, async (req, res) => {
    const type = req.query.type;
    let movie;
    try {
      if (type === "series") {
        movie = await Movie.aggregate([
          { $match: { isSeries: true } },
          { $sample: { size: 1 } },
        ]);
      } else {
        movie = await Movie.aggregate([
          { $match: { isSeries: false } },
          { $sample: { size: 1 } },
        ]);
      }
      res.status(200).json(movie); //checked here by console logging it comes here only once
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err); //the error pointing to this line
    }
});
```

Just in case, here is the verify function code:

```js
function verify(req,res,next) {
    const authHeader = req.headers.token;
    if(authHeader){
        const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];

        jwt.verify(token,process.env.SECRET_KEY,(err,user) => {
            if(err) res.status(403).json("Token is not valid");
            req.user = user;
            next();
        })
    } else{
        return res.status(401).json("Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

Comment: try changing this line :  res.status(403).json("Token is not valid"); to 
return res.status(403).json("Token is not valid");

Comment: @Aimsat Thanks a lot. That was the point. That was what causing the problem. It was causing two responses, got it.